# Who has access to my email address?

Tags: support

Does anyone on this site have access to my email address? Do moderators? Do employees?

What can they use it for?

---

<sup>I get this message unless I include this message: This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.</sup>

Comment: Anecdotal data: I have a single-use email address used for Stack Exchange purposes only. I've not received any inappropriate communications (at least, that have made it through my spam filters.)

Answer (score 4):

Mods and above can access your PII including email. They can't disclose your personal info and all access is logged.

Your email is used for a number of things, all of which are in conformance to our [privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy): sending you newsletters you sign up for, or delivering mod messages or other rare communication for example.

If you think your PII has been misused, the best course of action is [getting in touch with the community team](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact). We are very serious about your privacy.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators have access to your private information such as personal name and email address. However, as per the second section of moderator agreement, [they agree that](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement):

> ii. **I acknowledge that I may have access to potentially personally-identifying information about Stack Overflow users and that in connection with such access**
>
> a. I will use such information solely in accordance with the then-current Privacy Policy of Stack Overflow,
>
> b. **I will not disclose this information to anyone,**
>
> c. **I will not store or copy this information and**
>
> d. I will only use such information in connection with performance as a Stack Overflow moderator for the benefit of Stack Overflow.

Basically, they are not allowed to use it for the purpose of disclosing it and they are not allowed to copy or store your information.

Comment: Employees have a different agreement, for obvious reasons we store and manipulate PII, for example, but always without disclosing it etc.